# LG l70 DBI Err Fatal - boot up display stuck here

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, unbricking

I had LG l70 and I have rooted and fully unrooted it few times. Recently I fully unrooted it and factory reseted because I had intention to sell it. I left Lg l70 in sleep without battery in it for about 2 weeks and then I wanted to sell it, but when I booted up phone I got DBI Err Fatal. I have searched and tried every method to solve this, but the problem is I can't get phone to download or recovery mode. Everytime when I try to do it, it just displays DBI Err fatal. Even my computer can not recognise phone through USB connection. I am desperate for help.

Sincerely, divjad---

Here is the image of what it looks like everytime when it boots up.
[image: Boot up screen]